# High end ubuntu for 7 inch instead of 10 inch tablet

Tags: tablet, compatibility

I have read the specs for ubuntu touch. Is it possible to run it on a 7 or 8 inch quad core tablet instead of dual core processor if it meets all the other specs? Are these minimum specs or does it present a display problem if the screen is smaller than 10-12 inches?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ubuntu Tablet homepage, it will scale from 6.5" to 20".

"With unique multi-tasking productivity, secure sharing, and a beautiful interface which scales perfectly from 6.5” to 20” screens and beyond, Ubuntu releases new possibilities from the tablet, at work and at play."

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet